# Using Firebase Phone Numer Authentication And Save User Password into Firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Using Phone Number Authentication for sign up the user and then i add some info and password about the user in firebase realtime database. Now How can I authenticate an user for Log in ? is there any way !

Answer (score 0):

Use firebase Auth for demo check here https://fir-ui-demo-84a6c.firebaseapp.com/